# Checking a function before executing current function

Tags: vba, excel

I have created two separate functions on VBA.

Ideally, a user will have 2x buttons assigned to these macros. One button to validate the data `myCheck()` and the other button to submit the data `onSubmit()`.

`myCheck()` function is a Boolean and is set up to be either true of false as indicator whether to run `onSubmit()`.

So, if a user presses `onSubmit()` prior to validating the data, it should not submit the data as `myCheck()` was already initialised to `False`. See code below:

```
Function myCheck() As Boolean

    myCheck = False

    'Do checking operation
    If chkTEP = True And chkNULL = True Then
        Output = MsgBox("Validation complete", vbInformation, "Validation")    
        myCheck = True    
    ElseIf chkTEP = False And chkNULL = True Then
        Output = MsgBox("Double check your TEP combination", vbCritical, "Validation")    
        myCheck = False    
    ElseIf chkTEP = True And chkNULL = False Then
        Output = MsgBox("There is a blank cell", vbCritical, "Validation")    
        myCheck = False    
    Else:
        Output = MsgBox("Please make sure spreadhseet is filled correctly", vbCritical, "Validation")    
        myCheck = False    
    End If

End Function
```

As you can see from above, the function myCheck can either result in TRUE or FALSE.

The next step after this is to run another function onSubmit(). If myCheck is FALSE, then onSubmit will not work.. etc.

```
Sub onSubmit()

    If myCheck = False Then
        GoTo FuncEnder    
        Else
        'execute onSubmit function here    
    FuncEnder:

    End If

End Sub
```

What I discovered is once onSubmit() is executed, it runs the entire function myCheck(), rather than just checking its stored Boolean value.

Comment: You don't need a colon after `Else`. Colon is a replacement for new line, in case you want to keep code more compact.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this with 2 separate buttons? Why not write 2 functions, and then have 1 macro execute both? IF False, exit sub, else onSubmit.

Comment: Okay. How would you go about doing that?

Comment: If that’s not an option, you will need to declare a public variable to pass over between your functions OR have your first function place a value (true or false) in a cell on your workbook and have your second function check the cell value

Comment: Having one button to execute both is a great idea. But I am unsure how to do it? Unless I am over complicating it on my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button needs to be linked to the 'Execute' macro. It will first test your check and only execute submit when <> False. There is no need for 2 buttons when you can link all this together with one. You will get the same desired output with one less step needed by the user. I also changed your functions here to "Public Function"

Function 1

```
Public Function myCheck() As Boolean

'YOUR FUNCTION HERE

End Function
```

Function 2

```
Public Function onSubmit()

'YOUR FUNCTION HERE

End Function
```

Macro

```
Sub Execute()

If myCheck = False Then Exit Sub
Else
onSubmit

End Sub
```

Comment: Not Sure of on submit is function, I think that should be a SUB instead of function.

Comment: On OP's post, he has a comment line that says "Execute onSubmit function here" so I am assuming it is a function. OP, can you clarify?

Comment: But on its code, it is sub not a function, isn't it?

Comment: Sure is a contradiction between that comment and the sub name. If it is a sub, you just need to modify the execute macro to say "Call onSubmit"

Comment: Sorry guys, I am not sure what is the difference between SUB and Function? Otherwise, your solution is simple and elegant.

Comment: @OdaySalim A function is intended to return something. In OOP a sub should generally be  a set of instructions to achieve one task.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Public variable of myCheck  in your modules. Made is possible to check if the your first check button being pressed or not. For instance mybutton.tag = true.

```
Public myCheck as boolean
```

then everything should be OK. It runs as it will be always false.

```
Sub mybutton_click()

    myCheck  ' calls the mycheck function

    if mycheck then 
       mybutton.tag="true"
    else
       mybutton.tag = ""
    end if

end sub
```

then

on your second sub:

```
Sub onSubmit()

    if mybutton.tag <> "true" then 
       msgbox" You need to press Mycheck button First!"
       exit sub
    else
        If myCheck = False Then end sub   

        'execute onSubmit function here    

    End If

End Sub
```